# Why won't wget mirror the .zip files from this website?

Tags: wget

[This website](https://damieng.com/typography/zx-origins/) has links to a bunch of sub-pages like /zx-origins/sub-page, and those pages in turn have a link to a .zip file on a sub-domain. My goal is to get those .zip files in one nice command, I thought it would be a lot simpler than it turned out to be.

First of all I have made sure that the links are all server side rendered by using curl and grep, so I know the links exist before Javascript. I also have JS disabled in my browser.

The only inconsistency I see is that the final link to the .zip file has no protocol, just `//download.damieng.com`...

Is this a bug or a feature in wget not allowing me to follow links without a protocol?

My reasoning so far was that it should be relatively simple to do with wget's -m (mirror) and -A (accept list).

```
wget -m -e robots=off -D download.damieng.com,damieng.com -A .zip https://damieng.com/typography/zx-origins/
```

I've tried running it with -d (debug) and it doesn't even list the paths where the .zip file is linked, making me even more confused. I hope some wget ninja can enlighten me.

Comment: If your using wget on a https link you have to authenticate that secure https client. Your command doesn’t do that

Comment: @Ramhound what does that mean in practice?